# Como aplicações distribuídas (bitcoin, torrents...) encontram uns-aos-outros?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

Como os softwares distribuídos/descentralizados são capazes de estabelecer conexão e encontrar outras máquinas que estejam rodando o mesmo software?

No Bitcoin, por exemplo, como é que os "Full Nodes" se encontram uns aos outros? Como ele encontra "outra carteira" para se comunicar?

---

Alguns softwares descentralizados, como Torrent, utilizam um intermediário, salvo engano são chamados de Trackers, que permitem encontrar uns aos outros. Eles parecem agir como um DNS, *a grosso modo*, de maneira a obter endereço daqueles que possuem o arquivo baixado *e pode lhe enviar*.

---

Porém, se uma plataforma é distribuída, não havendo nenhum servidor central para obter informações, como que raios ele consegue achar os outros? Para mim, na minha concepção sempre vai existir um "intermediário", para possibilitar que um encontre os outros, estou certo? Existe uma outra maneira de possibilitar conexões de aplicativos "distribuídos"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No caso do protocolo Bitcoin, especificamente, não existe nenhum intermediário para que um cliente da rede encontre outros aos quais se conectar.
Um cliente Bitcoin, ao iniciar, vai tentar utilizar alguns métodos, em ordem, para descobrir outros nós na rede. Esses métodos são os seguintes:

- Todos os nós mantêm uma lista de outros nós conhecidos por ele, e se conecta preferencialmente a eles ao iniciar. Essa lista contém todos os nós aos quais ele já se conectou.

  O protocolo também possibilita que um nó peça a outro nó informações sobre  os nós ativos que ele conhece, por meio da mensagem [getaddr](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#getaddr). Os clientes mandam essa mensagem aos nós a que eles se conectam, com o objetivo de incrementar sua lista de nós conhecidos.

  Caso o cliente nunca tenha estado online antes, ele ainda não possui nenhum IP em sua lista de nós conhecidos, então vai precisar conseguir um utilizando o próximo método.
- Consultas DNS: Existe uma lista de domínios mantidos com o único propósito de fornecer uma lista de IPs que reconhecidamente estão rodando nós da rede Bitcoin, e esses domínios estão embutidos no código do cliente Bitcoin.
  Então basta uma consulta DNS nesses domínios para ter uma lista de nós inicial aos quais se conectar, e partir deles ir aumentando a base local de nós conhecidos.
  Pode-se ver [o trecho específico do código](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.14.2/src/chainparams.cpp#L123) onde esses domínios encontram-se, e o [trecho onde o cliente faz a consulta](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.14.2/src/net.cpp#L1554);
- Também existe uma lista de IP's de nós da rede Bitcoin embutida (hardcoded) no código , que será usada caso todos os outros métodos falhem. Essa lista pode ser vista [nessa parte do código](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.14.2/src/chainparamsseeds.h#L10), e é [utilizada aqui](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v0.14.2/src/net.cpp#L1705);
- O usuário também pode iniciar o seu cliente passando uma lista de IP's de nós aos quais ele deveria tentar se conectar inicialmente, mas nesse caso você teria que conhecer o IP de pelo menos um nó que já exista.
  Isso é feito por meio do parâmetro `-addnode=<ip>`. Uma lista dos parâmetros disponíveis pode ser vista [aqui](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Command-line_arguments).

Obs: Essa resposta e os links para o código no GitHub referem-se à versão `0.14.2`.

Comment: A resposta é boa mas acho que peca ao afirmar que: **não existe intermediário para que um cliente encontre outro**. A conexão inicial deve se conectar a um endereço (conhecido da rede) para requisitar ao menos **1** nó ativo. O protocolo define a opção [getaddr](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#getaddr) para isto. Após receber ao menos **1** endereço o cliente pode gerenciar a própria lista. O primeiro item de sua lista só ocorre a partir da segunda conexão e o ultimo item só é usado caso o usuário crie ou use um cliente alternativo ao qual não possuem a lista de ips ou dns's.

Comment: @LauroMoraes incrementei a resposta com suas informações.